# Logarithmic aptitude

Tags: logarithms

Given that $y>1$ and $x\ge y$, then $\log_{x}(x/y)+\log_{y}(x/y)$ can never be:

1. $-1$
2. $-0.5$
3. $0$
4. $1$

Please provide the answer with the solution and brief explanation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. I may quickly add that this is not a free homework site.

Comment: You must first give us your own thoughts in order to say if you are in the right way and if not to give you the right approach to the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\log_x\frac xy+\log_y\frac xy=$$

$$\log_xx-\log_xy+\log_yx-\log_yy=$$

$$1-\frac1{\log_yx}+\log_yx-1=$$

$$\log_yx-\frac1{\log_yx}\tag{1}$$

Introduce $a=\log_yx$. The expression (1) becomes:

$$a-\frac1a=\frac{a^2-1}a\tag{2}$$

...with $a$ having the following propery.

$$y>1,\space x\ge y\implies a\ge1$$

Obviously expression (2) cannot be negative for $a\ge1$ so you should drop the first two options. For $a=1$ expression (2) is equal to zero. I will leave it up to you to prove that the fourth option is possible. Just show that equation $a-\frac1a=1$ has a solution greater than 1.